# Showing html radio buttons using Perl?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I want to show 2 radio buttons used to select the gender of a student. When I try to set a variable using the [CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#CREATING-A-RADIO-BUTTON-GROUP) Perl module to produce html code for these radio buttons, only the radio selection text is showing, not the buttons:

```
$cInput_form .= $q->div({-class => 'control-group'},
                    $q->label({-class => 'control-label', -for => 'gender'}, "Gender:"), 
                    $q->div({class => 'controls'}, 
                    $q->span({class => 'span12'},
                    $q->label({-class => 'blue'},
                    $q->radio_group({-id => 'gender',name => 'gender', -values => ['M','F'], -labels => \%labels, -default => $cGender, 'true'}), $q->span({-class => 'lbl'})))));
```

When I use the "Insepect element" tool in my web browser the html I see is:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="gender">Gender:</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <span class="span12">
      <label class="blue">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" checked="checked" id="gender" true="">
          Male
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" id="gender" true="">
          Female
        </label>
        <span class="lbl"></span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think the problem is that `<span class = 'lbl'>` is not in the right place, but I don't know where else it should be. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that you are grouping the radio_group within unnecessary label groups. [This](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) page shows code similar to your situation for wanting to create a gender selection radio button group.

Try changing your code to(reformatted to make it a little more readable):

```
$cInput_form .= $q->div({-class => 'control-group'},
                $q->label({-class => 'control-label', 
                           -for   => 'gender'}, Gender:"), 
                $q->radio_group({-id => 'gender',
                                 name => 'gender', 
                                 -values => ['M','F'], 
                                 -labels => \%labels, 
                                 -default => $cGender, 
                                 'true'}),
                        );
```

This is untested but I think gets across the point, just be careful when grouping 1 section inside another. Hope it helps!